# JPA JOIN without cross joins

Tags: jpa, join

I'm trying to have a relationship between the following tables

COMBINE

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Combine.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Combine c")
@Table(name="COMBINE")
public class Combine implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int id;

    private int artistid;

    private int automated;

    private int eventid;

    private int locationid;

    @Column(name="main_artist")
    private int mainArtist;

    public Combine() {
    }
```

Event

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Event.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM Event e")
@Table(name="event")
public class Event implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int id;

    private boolean active;

    private String addbyspider;

    private int automated;

    @Lob
    private String description;

    private Timestamp doorsopen;

    private Timestamp endtime;

    private Timestamp lastfm;

    @Column(name="latest_update")
    private Timestamp latestUpdate;

    private int minimumageid;

    private String name;

    private Timestamp nolatertime;

    private int podiuminfo;

    @Column(name="short_description")
    private String shortDescription;

    @Column(name="sold_out")
    private int soldOut;

    private Timestamp time;

    @Column(name="update_by_bot")
    private Timestamp updateByBot;

    /* TO DO: LINK NAAR EVENTPRICE */
//  public EventPrice getEventPrice() {
//      return eventPrice;
//  }
//
//  public void setEventPrice(EventPrice eventPrice) {
//      this.eventPrice = eventPrice;
//  }
//
//  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "event_price")
//  private EventPrice eventPrice;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Artist
    //@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="COMBINE"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="eventid")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="artistid")
            }
        )
    private List<Artist> artists;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="eventid")
    private List<Combine> combine;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Location
    //@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="COMBINE"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="eventid")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="locationid")
            }
        )
    private List<Location> locations;
```

Location

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Location.findAll", query="SELECT l FROM Location l")
@Table(name="location")
public class Location implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int id;

    private boolean active;

    @Column(name="at_owner")
    private int atOwner;

    @Column(name="bad_ticket_site")
    private int badTicketSite;

    @Lob
    private String description;

    private int expectedBotItems;

    private int expectedBotRuntime;

    @Column(name="last_run")
    private Timestamp lastRun;

    private String name;

    private boolean notPrimaryBot;

    private int organisationid;

    private short priorityid;

    @Column(name="short_description")
    private String shortDescription;

    @Column(name="spider_by")
    private int spiderBy;
```

What this currently does is generate cross joins with the tables with the following TypedQuery

```
               StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("SELECT e FROM Event e, Combine c, Location l ");
sb.append("where e.id = c.eventid and l.id = c.locationid ");
sb.append("and e.time>=NOW() and e.soldOut='0' and e.active>=1");
```

This generates

```
select event0_.id as id1_26_,
 event0_.active as active2_26_,
  event0_.addbyspider as addbyspi3_26_,
   event0_.automated as automate4_26_,
    event0_.description as descript5_26_,
     event0_.doorsopen as doorsope6_26_,
      event0_.endtime as endtime7_26_,
       event0_.lastfm as lastfm8_26_,
        event0_.latest_update as latest_u9_26_,
         event0_.minimumageid as minimum10_26_,
          event0_.name as name11_26_,
           event0_.nolatertime as nolater12_26_,
            event0_.podiuminfo as podiumi13_26_,
             event0_.short_description as short_d14_26_,
              event0_.sold_out as sold_ou15_26_,
               event0_.time as time16_26_,
                event0_.update_by_bot as update_17_26_
                 from
                  event event0_
                   cross join COMBINE combine1_
                    cross join location location2_
                    where event0_.id=combine1_.eventid and location2_.id=combine1_.locationid and event0_.time>=now() and event0_.sold_out='0' and event0_.active>=1 limit ?
```

I do not want to create `CROSS JOINS` at all but instead I would like `INNER JOIN` between the tables. How could I achieve this?

There is something wrong with the OneToOne as it doesn't build to the server. Anyone know why this doesn't work?

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="eventid")
private List<Combine> combine;
```

Comment: You have to model the relationship in your entities. See `@ManyToOne`, `@OntToMany` and so on.

Comment: I have tried different relationships but to no success, how could I create a relation between event.id = combine.eventid and combine.locationid = location.id ?

Comment: You posted the exact same thing a day or so ago and I said then, you have NO RELATION in Event to Combine, and you are also using table COMBINE for the join table of MULTIPLE M-N relations. You need to fix your modelling BEFORE even thinking of queries! Now you delete the post and post it again. The answer is the same

Comment: The problem is I didn't actually create these models and never actually worked with JPA so I'm not really sure what to 'fix'. If you could send me in the right direction by giving me an example for my situation I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: As the other post said (before you deleted it) you can use JOIN to navigate across relations. "SELECT e FROM Event e JOIN e.combine c ..." will get you the  join to Combine entity. Any JPQL tutorial would tell you how to do a JOIN

Comment: However when I execute `SELECT e FROM Event e JOIN e.Combine c WHERE e.id = c.eventid` 

I get `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Combine of:`

Comment: THERE IS NO SUCH PROPERTY "Combine" in Event class. It is called "combine". Which is why in my comment I said "e.combine" not "e.Combine".

Comment: @NeilStockton `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: combine of:`
Same result.

Comment: Either Event has a field "private List<Combine> combine;" or it doesn't. If it does then you do that JOIN in your JPQL. Problems should be defined in the question ... not in the comments.

Comment: You still have table "COMBINE" being the join table for OneToMany/ManyToMany relations. It CANNOT DO THAT!

Comment: I still get the build error when I remove the ManyToMany relations with COMBINE.

Comment: Why oh why have you got a List field marked as OneToOne?! Just sort out your basic mapping before even trying to query anything